# How do you bind an event to data-value change in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, our designer decided on using HTML5 from now on.

He is using sliders with the following code:

```
<div data-layout="row fluid">
    <div class="span text-import text-shadow text-xbig text-left " data-layout="line middle">
        <a href="#" class="span" data-toggle="ajslider" data-value="1" data-target="parent.ui-slider">A</a>
        <div  class="span ui-slider slider-boolean" data-length="2" data-range="max">
            <div class="definition" data-icon="default"></div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="span" data-toggle="ajslider" data-value="2" data-target="parent.ui-slider">B</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The question is: How do you bind an event that triggers when value of data is changed (sliding, clicking the slider or clicking  the text)?

Update: it seems we got the wrong files, From the new file it seems he is using the following libraries:

- jQuery v1.8.2
- jQuery UI Widget 1.9.0
- jQuery UI Core 1.9.0
- jQuery UI Mouse 1.9.0
- jQuery UI Draggable 1.9.0
- jQuery UI Droppable 1.9.0

Comment: You might be using any plugin. So check its API what does that say. Or tell us which plugin you're using

Comment: I wish it was a plugin. He decided on using only HTML5 and CSS.

Comment: Be more specific as to what you mean by data change. Data in which element? And clicking on which text?

Comment: Clicking the A or B, and for data, it obviously changes on

<div  class="span ui-slider slider-boolean" data-length="2" data-range="max">
            <div class="definition" data-icon="default"></div>
        </div>

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jquery UI slider then there are specified events that you can use - http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

Comment: It's not jquery UI slider. It's pure HTML5.

Comment: it can't be html5 slider because you don't have an input in your code

Comment: @Pawel_W this what made me think he's using plugin